# Limit number of concurrent map tasks in Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop

I want to restrict number of simultaneously map tasks running at one slave node.

In my case, when I submit my job, Hadoop generate 8 map tasks, when I looked at Job history UI at port 19888, I always saw that 8 map tasks started at the same time at same slave node.

Even I tried to set this attribute `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` equal to 4 (from [how to restrict the concurrent running map tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14380841/how-to-restrict-the-concurrent-running-map-tasks)). It still didn't work for me.

Does anyone have a experiment to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

for hadoop 2.6 it should be newer API - [see this mapred-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml)

set `mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` to 4

> The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.

Comment: `mapreduce.job.maps` >The default number of map tasks per job. Ignored when mapreduce.jobtracker.address is "local".  - Do you have this set somewhere to 8? this might me overriding the max map task param

Comment: After checking, I don't set this value in the configuration,